# Poor Quality from USB Video Device on VLC

Tags: usb, video, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-capture

I am having trouble using VLC to use my USB Capture Card as it is outputting porr quality. The quality is blurry or pixilated. I have looked around on many forums and videos to see if they can help with this issue but so far, none of those fixes have worked.

Whenever I use OBS to stream my capture card video, the quality is perfect. I have added photos of each application streaming the same capture.

[VLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evEwz.png)

[OBS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEXzK.png)

Comment: Check here: https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/how-do-you-actually-save-or-export-a-capture-to-a-video-file-that-can-be-watched.104727/#post-560367

Comment: Fixed! I found an error within the Dshow settings of VLC that did not match up with what I was trying to put up with Open Capture Device.

Comment: I only found this out whenever I went into the Advanced Options for Capture Device and turned on Device Properties which by default set the Video Frame Rate to 30 and the Output Size to 640 x 480 even though the Picture aspect ratio was set to 16:9.

Comment: In short, it displayed the captured screen at a 16:9 Window, but did not adjust the capture to the same ratio and thus it made the screen all blurry and pixilated.